# Reviews in magento 2

Tags: frontend, magento2.2, knockoutjs, product-review

I have modified the **review form** in my custom module and makes the review form to show as a popup modal.And I don't need review tab. So I have  removed the review tab, after removing review tab it shows following js error.

**Error**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at run (layout.js:164)
>       at app.js:14
>       at main.js:31
>       at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>       at Module.check (require.js:866)
>       at Module. (require.js:1113)
>       at require.js:132
>       at require.js:1156
>       at each (require.js:57)

**If** I **remove** the **below part** in my **custom form.phtml**, the error is solved.

(In review module, **Magento\Review\View\frontend\templates\form.phtml**, Inside form.phtml)

```
"[data-role=product-review-form]": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
    },
```

Please explain me, I don't want to remove above code and also to solve my error.

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">XXX_YYY::review.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.review.popup" template="XXX_YYY::popup.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="custom.product.review.form" as="custom.review_form" template="XXX_YYY::form.phtml">
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView"  name="custom.product.section.info" template="XXX_YYY::abc.phtml"/> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Custom **form.phtml**

```
<?php


/** @var \Magento\Review\Block\Form $block */
?>
<div class="block review-add">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Write Your Own Review')) ?></strong></div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php if ($block->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()): ?>
            <form action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAction()) ?>" class="review-form" method="post" id="review-form" data-role="product-review-form" data-bind="scope: 'review-form'">
                <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>
                <fieldset class="fieldset review-fieldset" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
                    <legend class="legend review-legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("You're reviewing:")) ?></span><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?></strong></legend><br />
                    <?php if ($block->getRatings() && $block->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
                        <span id="input-message-box"></span>
                        <fieldset class="field required review-field-ratings">
                            <legend class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Rating')) ?></span></legend><br/>
                            <div class="control">
                                <div class="nested" id="product-review-table">
                                    <?php foreach ($block->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                                        <div class="field choice review-field-rating">
                                            <label class="label" id="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></span></label>
                                            <div class="control review-control-vote">
                                                <?php $options = $_rating->getOptions(); ?>
                                                <?php
                                                $iterator = 1;
                                                foreach ($options as $_option):
                                                    ?>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="radio"
                                                        name="ratings[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getId()) ?>]"
                                                        id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getValue()) ?>"
                                                        value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getId()) ?>"
                                                        class="radio"
                                                        data-validate="{required:true, messages:{required:'Please select one of each of the ratings above.'}}"
                                                        aria-labelledby="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getValue()) ?>_label" />
                                                    <label
                                                        class="rating-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($iterator) ?>"
                                                        for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getValue()) ?>"
                                                        title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star')) ?>"
                                                        id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getValue()) ?>_label">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star')) ?></span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <?php $iterator++; ?>
                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <div class="field review-field-nickname required">
                        <label for="nickname_field" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Nickname')) ?></span></label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: nickname()" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field review-field-text required">
                        <label for="review_field" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Review')) ?></span></label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().detail"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="actions-toolbar review-form-actions">
                    <div class="primary actions-primary">
                        <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit Review')) ?></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!--@TODO - need to check JS-->
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                "[data-role=product-review-form]": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
                },
                "#review-form": {
                "Magento_Review/js/error-placement": {}
                }
                }
            </script>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="message info notlogged" id="review-form">
                <div>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%1">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginLink(), $block->getRegisterUrl()), ['a']) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope [this link](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-write-a-page-using-magento-2-knockout-js/) will help you to understand how knockout js works in magento 2

Comment: Thank you, I have reffered that link but unable to understand What is data-role & data scope

Comment: Hi @ Sri, let me know how did you remove the reviews tab from the product details page?

Comment: Hi, @Mgento please see the above catalog file,                        
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        </referenceBlock>

Comment: Please post your custom form.phtml too

Comment: @MGento  I have updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your `catalog_product_view.xml` as follows

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">XXX_YYY::review.phtml</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.review.popup" template="XXX_YYY::popup.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="custom.product.review.form" as="custom.review_form" template="XXX_YYY::form.phtml">
                <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="review-form" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review/js/view/review</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView"  name="custom.product.section.info" template="XXX_YYY::abc.phtml"/> 
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Now clear your cache and refresh.

Comment: No, still it shows an error

Comment: I have done as you said ,But now my product image is still loading and review popup is not shown, Now the error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 150

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please  try it. Copy paste the whole xml and clear your cache.

Comment: No , Now the error is solved (When I tried to hide the reviews tab then only  the error is occurs),But failed to hide reviews tab , and it works as default , Not as per my custom module(Failed to show popup)

Comment: let me try again. I have updated the xml. Please try the new xml content , clear cache and check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70219/discussion-between-sri-and-mgento).