# Magento2: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: magento2, customer, blocks, json

[image]

The above code is written in catalog_product_view.xml in module-catalog.
For this block, customer info in the header after login not loading. In console I'm getting this error:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

If I comment on this block it works well. Any solution for this?

Thank You

Comment: Instead of checking the xml can you please check the template code. May be something wrong in that. Try both the ways.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue if any one is having the solution then please, advice. I have added customer Review Tab in custom theme but success message for review posted is displaying in when I view other page. And when I try to add product it is not displaying success message for product.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just have to add

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="review-form" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review/js/view/review</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```

Right after

```
<container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
```

Don't forget to flush Magento cache with the usual command :

```
bin/magento c:f;
```

Source : [Reviews in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205759/reviews-in-magento-2/205792)